# Izpack Uninstaller.jar is not working when install using console option

Tags: java, izpack

I have created a installation.jar file for my project using Izpack. when I try to install it using GUI command like(java -jar installation.jar) then it's created a correct uninstallation.jar in Uninstallation directory.but when i try to install it using console command like (java -jar installation.jar -console) then it's not created a correct unistallation.jar file in Unistallation directory.

Answer (score 0):

This was a known bug around the time of 4.3.4. It has since been fixed in later versions. Nothing you're doing wrong. :)